# Get data depending by the element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application where I want to implement the next logic. When I click on a `div`, I want to get data from that `div`.

```js
import React from 'react';

const Test = () => {
  const data = [{
      name: 'John',
      last: 'Doe',
      age: 22,
      id: 1

    },
    {
      name: 'Bill',
      last: 'Doe',
      age: 5,
      id: 2
    }
  ];

  const getRowData = (dataRow) => {
    console.log(dataRow)
  };

  return ( <div>
    <div> {
      data.map(i => {
        return <div onClick = {
          getRowData(i)
        }
        style = {
          {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            height: '50px',
            width: '200px',
            border: '1px solid white'
          }
        } > {
          i.name
        } </div>
      })
    } </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

For example, if I click on first `div`, I want to get all data about that person:

```
name: 'John',
last: 'Doe',
age: 22,
id: 1
```

But now, the onClick function does not work properly, because on the first render I get all data in the console, but I need to get data only about one person and only after I click on a specific element. How to solve this?

**Demo**: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-blackwell-98r0g?file=/src/App.js:0-747

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking it immediately when you specify it as `onClick={getRowData(i)}` with the parens. If you specify it as anonymous function it'll work,  `onClick={() => getRowData(i)}`.

```
{data.map(i => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => getRowData(i)}
      style={{backgroundColor:'red', height:'50px', width:'200px', border:'1px solid white'}}
    >
      {i.name}
    </div>
  )
})}
```

The other option is to define the `getRowData` callback as a curried function:

```
getRowData = index => event => {...
```

The outer function is invoked immediately and returns the *actual* callback function to be used with the passed `index` enclosed in function scope.

Then you can simply assign is as you have:

```
{data.map(i => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={getRowData(i)}
      style={{backgroundColor:'red', height:'50px', width:'200px', border:'1px solid white'}}
    >
      {i.name}
    </div>
  )
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

Look at the second arrow function, is to prevent to be called each render:

```js
const getRowData =(dataRow) => () => {
       console.log(dataRow)
};
```

And then get your item:

```js
const getRowData =(dataRow) => () => {
    const item = data.find(d => d.id === dataRow.id);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.On click of each item . you will get the corresponding object

```
import React from "react";

const Test = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      name: "John",
      last: "Doe",
      age: 22,
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Bill",
      last: "Doe",
      age: 5,
      id: 2
    }
  ];

  const getRowData = dataRow => {
    console.log(dataRow);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {data.map((data, i) => {
          return (
            <div
              onClick={() => getRowData(data)}
              key={data.name}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "red",
                height: "50px",
                width: "200px",
                border: "1px solid white"
              }}
            >
              {data.name}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```